# application name and apps script version

Tags: google-app-maker

how to change the application name created by appmaker.
I have got a dialog in published first page (image below).
but I want to change "Hello App Maker! (copy)"..
[image]
and where is apps script project connected appmaker?
I have not found in apps script dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to open the GCP Project. If you are doing a preview, then you'll have to click the link that says **Server Logs**, which is usually located on the bottom left:

[image]

If you want to do it on a deployed version, then you'll need to open the edit section of the deployment and click on **VIEW LOGS**:

[image]

Once you are taken to the GCP project, click the menu icon on the top right and select **Project settings**:

[image]

Finally, change the project name and click **SAVE*:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! "log" is where to go the GCP entrance that is very hard to understand..